# Duplicate class com.google.firebase.auth.ktx.AuthKt found in modules || Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

These are my errors in Logcat while building the app. I am shifting this app from 1 Firebase account to another. but the dependencies are throwing errors like this.
How do I clear these errors? The app is not building, it is giving errors on the app build:

```
    Duplicate class com.google.firebase.auth.ktx.AuthKt found in modules jetified-              
    firebase-auth-22.3.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:22.3.0) and 
    jetified-firebase-auth-ktx-21.1.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth- 
    ktx:21.1.0)
    Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.ktx.ChildEvent found in modules 
    jetified-firebase-database-20.3.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase- 
    database:20.3.0) and jetified-firebase-database-ktx-20.1.0-runtime 
    (com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx:20.1.0)
    Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.ktx.ChildEvent$Added found in modules 
    jetified-firebase-database-20.3.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase- 
    database:20.3.0) and jetified-firebase-database-ktx-20.1.0-runtime 
    (com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx:20.1.0)
    Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.ktx.ChildEvent$Changed found in modules 
    jetified-firebase-database-20.3.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase- 
    database:20.3.0) and jetified-firebase-database-ktx-20.1.0-runtime 
    (com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx:20.1.0)
    Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.ktx.ChildEvent$Moved found in modules 
    jetified-firebase-database-20.3.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase- 
    database:20.3.0) and jetified-firebase-database-ktx-20.1.0-runtime 
    (com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx:20.1.0)
    Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.ktx.ChildEvent$Removed found in modules 
    jetified-firebase-database-20.3.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase- 
    database:20.3.0) and jetified-firebase-database-ktx-20.1.0-runtime 
    (com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx:20.1.0)
    Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.ktx.DatabaseKt found in modules 
    jetified-firebase-database-20.3.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase- 
    database:20.3.0) and jetified-firebase-database-ktx-20.1.0-runtime 
    (com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx:20.1.0)
    Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.ktx.DatabaseKt$childEvents$1 found in 
    modules jetified-firebase-database-20.3.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase- 
    database:20.3.0) and jetified-firebase-database-ktx-20.1.0-runtime 
    (com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx:20.1.0)
    Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.ktx.DatabaseKt$childEvents$1$1 found in 
    modules jetified-firebase-database-20.3.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase- 
    database:20.3.0) and jetified-firebase-database-ktx-20.1.0-runtime 
    (com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx:20.1.0)
    Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.ktx.DatabaseKt$childEvents$1$listener$1 
    found in modules jetified-firebase-database-20.3.0-runtime 
    (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.3.0) and jetified-firebase-database-ktx- 
    20.1.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx:20.1.0)
    Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.ktx.DatabaseKt$getValue$1 found in 
    modules jetified-firebase-database-20.3.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase- 
    database:20.3.0) and jetified-firebase-database-ktx-20.1.0-runtime 
    (com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx:20.1.0)
    Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.ktx.DatabaseKt$getValue$2 found in 
    modules jetified-firebase-database-20.3.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase- 
    database:20.3.0) and jetified-firebase-database-ktx-20.1.0-runtime 
    (com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx:20.1.0)
    Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.ktx.DatabaseKt$snapshots$1 found in 
    modules jetified-firebase-database-20.3.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase- 
    database:20.3.0) and jetified-firebase-database-ktx-20.1.0-runtime 
    (com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx:20.1.0)
    Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.ktx.DatabaseKt$snapshots$1$1 found in 
    modules jetified-firebase-database-20.3.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase- 
    database:20.3.0) and jetified-firebase-database-ktx-20.1.0-runtime 
    (com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx:20.1.0)
    Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.ktx.DatabaseKt$snapshots$1$listener$1 
    found in modules jetified-firebase-database-20.3.0-runtime 
    (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.3.0) and jetified-firebase-database-ktx- 
    20.1.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx:20.1.0)
    Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.ktx.FirebaseDatabaseKtxRegistrar found 
    in modules jetified-firebase-database-20.3.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase- 
    database:20.3.0) and jetified-firebase-database-ktx-20.1.0-runtime 
    (com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx:20.1.0)

    Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.
```

My build.gradle code is :

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'kotlin-android'
id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
compileSdk 34

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.socialtap.app"
    minSdk 24
    targetSdk 33
    versionCode 3
    versionName "1.3"
    multiDexEnabled = true
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 
        'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}
buildFeatures {
    viewBinding true
}
namespace 'com.socialtap.app'

}

dependencies {

implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.7.6'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.7.6'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'

// Firebase
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.0.1')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-ktx'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx'

//declare the dependency for the Google Play services library and specify its version
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.7.0'

//multiDex
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'

// image
implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.13.2"

//MaterialSpinner
implementation 'com.jaredrummler:material-spinner:1.3.1'

//sdp
implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.1.0'

//TedImagePicker
implementation 'com.github.dhaval2404:imagepicker:2.1'

//Coroutines
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.4'
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.4'
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.6.4'

//CircleImageView
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'

//Loader
implementation 'com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.4.0'

//Retrofit and GSON
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:5.0.0-alpha.3'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:5.0.0-alpha.3'

//ImageCompressor
implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:3.0.1'

//NFC
implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:31.0.1-jre'

//QRCode
implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.5.1'

//Facebook Login
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:14.1.1'

//Zoomable Image
implementation 'com.jsibbold:zoomage:1.3.1'
implementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit-ktx:1.1.5'
implementation 'androidx.test:monitor:1.6.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:22.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.3.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'

//QRCodeScanner
implementation 'com.github.yuriy-budiyev:code-scanner:2.3.2'
implementation 'com.github.kenglxn.QRGen:android:3.0.1'

//Permissions
implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:6.2.3'

}
```

The other gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub- 
projects/modules.
buildscript {
  repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.1'
    classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0'
  }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
   }
}


task clean(type: Delete) {
  delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code which is related to duplicate classes arises because you have duplicate dependencies:

```
// Firebase
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.0.1')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-ktx'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx'
```

And

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:22.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.3.0'
```

When you're using BOM there is no need to specify the versions for your dependencies. So you're mixing the versions that are provided by the BOM with ones that have been manually added, hence the error. To solve this, simply remove the following lines of code and sync your project again.

```
//implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:22.3.0' //
//implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.3.0' //
```